# If i have base class in package1 with protected method

Tags: java, class, inheritance, package, protected

if I have base class in package1 with protected method
child class in package2 overriding that protected method
Test class in package of base class has code that will create object of child in reference of base
if try to invoke the protected method what will happen?
It will call the child class method. Could you please let me know the reason behind it.. why it is so?

```
package base;

public class Base {
    protected void method()
    {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }

}

package base;

import child.Derived;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b = new Derived();
        b.method();
    }
}

package child;

import base.Base;

public class Derived extends Base {
    protected void method()
    {
        System.out.println("Derived");
    }

}
```

If I tried to create a Derived class object in Test class and access method like this

```
Derived d = new Derived();
    d.method();
```

It gives compile time error. Then how method is visible through base class reference.
How this internally works in java terms of access?

Comment: This is how polymorphism works.

Answer (score 1):

It is the method overriding(also see [dynamic binding](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html)) in java. Inherited class can access the `protected` methods , so you are allowed to override the method in the child class.

As you instantiate the sub class , you invoke the overridden method.If you wish you call the super class method. you can use the [`super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) keyword explicitly

Comment: please update your question with code . dont post it as comment